# Express routing error "cast to number failed for value "style.css" at path"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

I know this type of question already asked here . I have also looked at following question .  But it didn't help , those question deals with when parameter is the mongoose object id . But in my case `batch_id` is not mongoose object id .

[What's Mongoose error Cast to ObjectId failed for value XXX at path “_id”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985332/express-mongoose-router-cast-to-objectid-failed-for-value-undefined-at-path)

[Express/Mongoose Router: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value “undefined” at path “_id”'](http://Express/Mongoose%20Router:%20'Cast%20to%20ObjectId%20failed%20for%20value%20%E2%80%9Cundefined%E2%80%9D%20at%20path%20%E2%80%9C_id%E2%80%9D')

Here is what i did .

```
router.route("/view_by_batch/?:batchid").get(function(req,res){


    if(req.session.user){
        barcodeEntry.find({batch_id:req.params.batchid},function(err, data) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            res.render('view_by_batch',{ data: data,batch_no:req.params.batchid});
        });
    }else {
        res.render('index',{auth:false});
    }

});
```

I am getting the following error in console

```
message: 'Cast to number failed for value "style.css" at path "batch_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'number',
  value: 'style.css',
  path: 'batch_id' }
```

Even I removed the link of `style.css` file but , it didn't help .

Answer (score 2):

When your page is loading, along with, it loads the styles.css file which is wrongly being routed.

So when the :batchid is being sent, it first sends the desired id first and then immediately "styles.css" file is also gets loaded and it is pointing to a wrong path.

So actually your routing is incorrect.

This is what you should do:

1. Include following line in your app.js file.

   ```
   app.use(express.static( __dirname + "/public"));
   ```
2. In your styles.css link tag,

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/>
   ```
3. In my case, styles.css file is saved in public/stylesheets/style.css, Please follow instructions according to your own folder structure.
4. Notice the '/' at the start of href in link tag.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is that in your schema you set batch_id as number and you are passing style.css (a string) in the query. Mongoose is trying to do something like parseFloat('style.css') but it fails. So please make sure `{batch_id:req.params.batchid}` in

```
barcodeEntry.find({batch_id:req.params.batchid},function(err, data)
```

is something meaningful.

According to [Express Doc1](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html). `?` in the path will be treated as a regular expression character. If you just want to match the path param. It's better to set it like

```
router.route("/view_by_batch/:batchid")
```

You can see [Express Doc](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) for more info about req.params in Express

Comment: Hi David. It's best to ask questions using the comment feature rather than as an answer to the question. It's likely that non-answers will get removed. If you think this is the answer to the question, perhaps rephrase it?

Comment: hi @stef. Thanks for you advice. However, I cannot add comment due to insufficient credits. I did update it a bit to make it like an answer even though I am not 100% sure it is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have met some problem like this. It is caused by the router order.

You may do like this:

```
router.route("/some/:id")
    .get(function(){
        // your code
    })

router.route("/some/other")
    .get(function(){
        // your code
    })
```

Just due to the **"/some/:id"** route is before **"/some/other"** route. When you send a GET request to **"/some/other"**, express considers **"other"** as a parameter of **"/some/:id"** route. So you will meet the CastError.

Solution:

***Let the route with "id" at the bottom of any other with the same prefix route, the problem will be solved.***

```
router.route("/some/other")
    .get(function(){
        // your code
    })

router.route("/some/:id")
    .get(function(){
        // your code
    })
```

[Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.param)